# Subtracting a fraction by -1, simplifies to putting -n on the numerator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, rational-numbers

Math Question:
You share 60 dollars between a certain number of people.

Each person gets 1 dollar more than if you had shared the $60 between 2 more people.

How many people are you sharing the 60 dollars between?

I have the answer in the image below:

[Question and Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey3AD.png)

I would like some explanation, firstly for what `a` represents (I'm thinking each person)?

And how $\dfrac {60}{n}-1$ simplifies to $\dfrac {60-n}{n}$

Also how it then becomes evaluated to $60n = (60-n)(n+2)$ (Perhaps cross multiplication?)

Cheers

Comment: Please write up the question here instead of relying on people to click through.  Links can rot and do not play well with screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If you have the fraction $\dfrac {1}{2}+ \dfrac {1}{3}$, what would you need to make the denominators the same?

Comment: Oh, it is cross multiplication... I just found out. Thanks

Comment: It is.  The common denominator between $\frac {1}{2}$ and $\frac {1}{3}$ is $6$, so each fraction with that common denominator would be $\frac {3}{6}$ and $\frac {2}{6}$, which is $\frac {5}{6}$.

Ergo, the common denominator for your fraction is $n$, and since $1 = \frac {n}{n}$, you have $\frac {60-n}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

A represents amount given to those people which are represented as n. This amount is a dollar less if you have the +2 for the people in the denominator. So we begin with two equations involving fractions.
The picture then takes the left equation that's solved for a and uses substitution to put into the other equation on the right. Then, because we have a fraction equal to another fraction they use cross multiplication (not required but saved a step). Finally they get common denominators, foil and simplify numeratora, and move everything to one side which gives a quadratic equation. They use the diamond method to solve for n which gives two real solutions but throw away the negative answer because you can't have negative amount of people which leaves 10 as the answer.

Comment: I think the solution is hard to understand.